# Where do I find whether I did or did not send an Outlook read receipt?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365, read

In Outlook (Office 365, desktop app) I sometimes receive an email with a read receipt request. My Outlook settings are such that Outlook always asks me if I want to answer that request. Sometimes I click Yes, sometimes I click No. Now I want to see whether I allowed or denied sending the read receipt. I cannot find such receipt confirmations in my Sent Items. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Answer (score 0):

After you have sent a "Read" receipt (you had to do a send/receive), there is no indication that the "Read" receipt had been used.

I have a number of emails here where the sender always asks for a "Read" receipt and I honor that on two computers (because I get the email on two computers) and there is no indication that there was a "Read" receipt (or none, if that is the case).

This is Outlook 365.